# PHP Session does not work when accesing via non-PHP extensions

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, session, session-variables

I'm having a bizarre problem accessing php SESSION data from an HTML page. I have a basic login.php which I redirect to 'page1.html.' Now I have configured the .htaccess as such:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

Plus, I know that my php code is working on any given HTML page.

However, if I put :

```
session_start();

....

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header ("Location: http://blahblahblah/Login.html");
}
```

inside the body of page1.html, the if statement always fires (in fact, a `var_dump($_SESSION) yields "array(0) { }"`).

But, if I take the same code, put it in 'page1.php,' everything works as expected (and a `var_dump($_SESSION) gives proper values).`

So, is it not possible to access `$_SESSION` from an HTML page the same way you would if its extension was renamed to `'.php'`? Or is there something I am doing wrong here? I would rather like to keep most of my pages as `'.html'` as opposed to `'.php,'` as it would be an inconvenience to go back and change all the file extensions, etc.

Much appreciated,

Comment: Have you called `session_start()` before trying to access `$_SESSION`?

Comment: have you tried to `session_start()` in `page1.html` ?

Comment: You shouldn't keep all `PHP` with `HTML` extension. Why do you need that when you can easily hide all extension or just add another rewrite rule for php scripts!?

Comment: @alfasin This is wrong. He said he forced Apache to interpret `php` scripts with `html` extension

Comment: It's even possibly to interpret any PHP script with random extension, like `.pl`, `.rb`, `.py`, `.jsp`, or even `.do`

Comment: Ahh, forgot to mention that. Yes, session_start() is called. Will edit.

Comment: @metal_fan Could you explain your second comment further?

Comment: @oIovoIo I meant `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .pl .rb .jsp .whatever`

Comment: Are the two files identical apart from the extension (html vs. php)?

Comment: @metal_fan my bad - I skipped it...

Comment: @DWright Yes, identical except for extension

Comment: Just for kicks, what happens if you add a `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .junkextension` and you put the code in a file with that extension?  If that works, perhaps that is some pre/post processing of html files going on.

Comment: @DWright Hmm, same result with .junkextension as with .html

Comment: Well, I guess that means you cannot solve your problems with .junkextension.  8=].  Not sure what else it means.  Guess the problem is *NOT* specific to .html.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described, PHP is functioning correctly (because the if statement is triggering).

Some things to check:

- Is `session_start()` being called in page1.html? This must be called to retrieve the session data and populate the `$_SESSION` super global.
- Is `session_start()` being called before the headers are sent? Check that the session is started before any HTML or whitespace is sent, otherwise the session cookie will not be sent with the headers.
- Are Login.html and page1.html on the same domain and same subdomain?  `$_SESSION` may be empty if the session cookie is unavailable.  This could happen if you are trying to use sessions across domains.
- Is there a session cookie and is it being sent?  While navigating to page1.html, check using Firebog/Inspector etc. to make sure that the session cookie exists, and that it is being passed with the request for the page.
- How is the `$_SESSION` variable being set?  It may just be coincidence that page1.php works because the `$_SESSION` variable may not have been properly set when you first tried to access page1.html
- Does Apache have permissions to write to the `session.save_path` declared in php.ini?
- Is the `session.save_path` a valid path?

Comment: 1st and 2nd point - yes. Fine on both those.

3rd point - Huh. So I've been working in chrome (for better or worse) and I opened firefox to check it out, and instead of loading page1.html like chrome does (and getting to the !isset) firefox gives a "Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: Interesting, looks like the session cookie is not being set because the  Apache is not able to write to `/tmp` (the default session path).  Try setting the session path to within your document root. `session_save_path(realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/session'));`  You may need to create this directory and will need to call the `session_save_path` on each page where you are using sessions.

Comment: I can't say I have a whole lot of experience with this, so sorry if I'm slow on the uptake. So I would put that line around where I would put session_start() in files like page1.html?

Comment: Yes, you can incude that line before session_start (which should be at the very top of your file, before any HTML or whitespace).  Alternatively, you may be able to set it in your .htaccess file using `php_value session.save_path ./sessions`

Comment: Hmm, tried that, didn't have much luck. I need to get moving along on this project, so at this point I think I'll just take the time to switch the relevant file extensions to .php and then this isn't an issue... Thank you though...